# Data type or constraint for storing a month

Tags: postgresql, validation, date, constraints

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "MovieFees" (

"Id" serial8 NOT NULL,

"LocalizedMovieId" int8 NOT NULL,

"Fees" int8 NOT NULL CHECK ("Fees" > 0),

"Month" date NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY ("Id") ,

CONSTRAINT "LocalizedMovieIdMonthUniq" UNIQUE ("LocalizedMovieId", "Month")

);
```

This table stores a data about profit some Movie for each month. For example,

```
The Maze Runner|100$|2014-10-01
The Maze Runner|200$|2014-11-02
Lucy|400$|2014-10-02
Lucy|100$|2014-11-03
Lucy|200$|2014-11-07 -- this is a error!
```

I want, the record (movie name + month name) is unique. But I want to store a date, not a name or index of month. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to store a date? Why is '2014-11-07' the error instead of '2014-11-03'?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', I want to store a date, because this is a date. If product owner wants to get reports for other date period, I can make them. '2014-11-07' is the error, because there is a report already for Lucy for 2014-11 month.

Comment: *"If product owner wants to get reports for other date period, I can make them."* What other date period?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall, for example, He may want to get report for each 2 weeks or each year.

Comment: If you restrict data to one row per month per movie, you can't possibly report sensibly on two-week periods.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', yep, today it is true. But, if I store date type, then I can remove this restrict and create needed report. Therefore I want to store a date, not index or name of month.

Comment: Removing the constraint next year won't manufacture data for *this* year. Seriously, your idea is wrong in so many ways I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', okay, I will not do this constraint. Thank you for this consultation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this will work, but I would try:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_month on MovieFees (date_trunc('month', Month))
```